# Multi-Step Form Required Fields To Go to Next Step

Tags: javascript, forms, multi-step

I'm trying to merge two codes for several days now without success. Is there someone who can help me with that please ? I'm a total beginner with web developpment, i'm sorry if it's a mess. It's all copy-paste essentially. The first part of the javascript is working with no issues, the second part of it has to be "added" to the first one.

```js
/* Multistep code */

const prevBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-prev");
const nextBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-next");
const progress = document.getElementById("progress");
const formSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".form-step");
const progressSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-step");

let formStepsNum=0;

nextBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      formStepsNum++;
      updateFormSteps();
      updateProgressbar();
    });
  });
  
  prevBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      formStepsNum--;
      updateFormSteps();
      updateProgressbar();
    });
  });
  
  function updateFormSteps() {
    formSteps.forEach((formStep) => {
      formStep.classList.contains("form-step-active") &&
        formStep.classList.remove("form-step-active");
    });
  
    formSteps[formStepsNum].classList.add("form-step-active");
  }
  
  function updateProgressbar() {
    progressSteps.forEach((progressStep, idx) => {
      if (idx < formStepsNum + 1) {
        progressStep.classList.add("progress-step-active");
      } else {
        progressStep.classList.remove("progress-step-active");
      }
    });
  
    const progressActive = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-step-active");
  
    progress.style.width =
      ((progressActive.length - 1) / (progressSteps.length - 1)) * 100 + "%";
  }

/*Validation code*/

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn-next").click(function(){
    var form = $("#register-user");
    form.validate({
      errorElement: 'span',
      errorClass: 'help-block',
      highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.input-group').addClass("has-error");
      },
      unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.input-group').removeClass("has-error");
      },
      rules: {
        first_name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
        },
        last_name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
        },
        user_login: {
          required: true,
        },
        user_pass: {
          required: true,
        },
        user_pass2: {
          required: true,
          equalTo: '#user_pass',
        },
        user_email: {
          required: true,
        },
        
      },      
      messages: {
        first_name: {
          required: "First name required",
        },
        last_name: {
            required: "Last name required",
        },
        user_login: {
            required: "Username required",
        },
        user_pass: {
          required: "Password required",
        },
        user_pass2: {
          required: "Password required",
          equalTo: "Password don't match",
        },
        user_email: {
          required: "Email required",
        },
      }
    });


if (form.valid() === true){
}})});
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post" class="form" id="register-user">
<!-- progress bar -->
<div class="progressbar">
<div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
    <div class="progress-step progress-step-active" data-title="Intro"></div>
    <div class="progress-step" data-title="contract"></div>
    <div class="progress-step" data-title="ID"></div>
    <div class="progress-step" data-title="Password"></div>
</div>
<!-- steps -->
<div class="form-step form-step-active">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder='Prenom' required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder='Nom' required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" value= "<?php echo isset($_POST['user_login']) ? $_POST['user_login'] : ''?>" name="user_login" id="user_login" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" required>
        </div>


    <div class="">
        <a href="#Step2" class="btn btn-next width-50 ml-auto">Suivant</a>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="form-step">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="occupation" id="reg_nurse" value="Registered Nurse" required>
            <label for="reg_nurse">Registered Nurse</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="occupation" id="prac_nurse" value="Practical Nurse" required>
            <label for="prac_nurse">Practical Nurse</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="occupation" id="nurse_prac" value="Nurse Practioner" required>
            <label for="nurse_prac">Nurse Practioner</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="occupation" id="midwife" value="Midwife" required>
            <label for="midwife">Midwife</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="occupation" id="reg_nurse_anes" value="Registered Nurse Anesthetist" required>
            <label for="reg_nurse_anes">Registered Nurse Anesthetist</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="occupation" id="nurse_spec" value="Nurse Specialist" required> 
            <label for="nurse_spec">Nurse Specialist</label>
        </div>

    </div>
        <div class="btns-group">
            <a href="#Step1" class="btn btn-prev">Précédent</a>
            <a href="#Step3" class="btn btn-next">Suivant</a>
        </div>
</div>
        
<div class="form-step">
    <div class="container2">

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="contract" id="trav_cont" value="Travel Contact" required>
            <label for="trav_cont">Travel Contact</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="contract" id="FT_staf_pot" value="Full-time Staff Position" required>
            <label for="FT_staf_pot">Full-time Staff Position</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="contract" id="PT_staf_pot" value="Part-time Staff Position" required>
            <label for="PT_staf_pot">Part-time Staff Position</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="radio" name="contract" id="not_work" value="Not Working" required>
            <label for="not_work">Not Working</label>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="btns-group">
            <a href="#Step2" class="btn btn-prev">Précédent</a>
            <a href="#Step4" class="btn btn-next">Suivant</a>
        </div>
</div>
        
<div class="form-step">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" value= "<?php echo isset($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : ''?>" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder='Votre email' required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" placeholder='Votre mot de passe' required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">   
            <input type="password" name="user_pass2" id="user_pass2" placeholder='Confirmez votre mot de passe' required>
        </div>

        <div class="btns-group">
            <a href="#Step3" class="btn btn-prev">Précédent</a>
            <input classe="btnsub" value="Inscription" type="submit" style="padding: 0.75rem; display: block; text-decoration: none; background-color: #5ecfb6; color: rgb(41, 41, 41); text-align: center; border-radius: 25px; cursor: pointer; transition: 0.3s; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 100; border: none;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, have you checked the error that you're getting? What does the error say? Try copying and pasting the error message into google.